How to use the TAdvSmoothImageListBox control in Delphi to scroll vertically?
I use tAdvSmoothImageListBox in the tms component, but I don't know how to make the image scroll vertically because it defaults to horizontal scrolling.

TMS has their own support forums that might be better for this post.
